# magento 2 order grid loading issue after data migration

Tags: magento2, orders, grid, order-grid, critical

1. `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAdditionalInformation() on null in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php:172`
2. Verified found that file method contains below code

> ```
> /**
>      * Set additional info to the order.
>      *
>      * @param OrderInterface $order
>      * @return void
>      */
>     private function setPaymentAdditionalInfo(OrderInterface $order): void
>     {
>         $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
>         $paymentAdditionalInformation = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
>
>         $objects = [];
>         foreach ($paymentAdditionalInformation as $key => $value) {
>             /** @var PaymentAdditionalInfoInterface $additionalInformationObject */
>             $additionalInformationObject = $this->paymentAdditionalInfoFactory->create();
>             $additionalInformationObject->setKey($key);
>
>             if (!is_string($value)) {
>                 $value = $this->serializer->serialize($value);
>             }
>             $additionalInformationObject->setValue($value);
>
>             $objects[] = $additionalInformationObject;
>         }
>         $extensionAttributes->setPaymentAdditionalInfo($objects);
>         $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
>     }
> ```

3. Verified and understand that the issue **sales_order** records count is not matching with **sales_order_payment** count.

Ex: sales_order count is: 99999
      sales_order_payment is: 88888

Here Could you please help me & advise.

Comment: same issue occur for me. @Nagaraju K you got any solution for this issue.

Comment: @Soundararajanm the issue with the records count sales_order vs sales_order_payment doesn't match while doing data migration

Comment: i know that issue details, u can fix that issue via code?

Comment: @NagarajuK can you help me on this question i think same  but payment gateway different https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/309805/86511

Answer (score 2):

I got solution for this issue.

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
     <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository" type="Vendor\Module\Model\OrderRepository"/>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\OrderRepository">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">orderMetadata</argument>
    </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Model\OrderRepository.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterfaceFactory as SearchResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata;
use Magento\Tax\Api\OrderTaxManagementInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Api\Data\PaymentAdditionalInfoInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Api\Data\PaymentAdditionalInfoInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json as JsonSerializer;

/**
 * Repository class
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class OrderRepository implements \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Metadata
     */
    protected $metadata;

    /**
     * @var SearchResultFactory
     */
    protected $searchResultFactory = null;

    /**
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    private $orderExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @var ShippingAssignmentBuilder
     */
    private $shippingAssignmentBuilder;

    /**
     * @var CollectionProcessorInterface
     */
    private $collectionProcessor;

    /**
     * @var OrderInterface[]
     */
    protected $registry = [];

    /**
     * @var OrderTaxManagementInterface
     */
    private $orderTaxManagement;

    /**
     * @var PaymentAdditionalInfoFactory
     */
    private $paymentAdditionalInfoFactory;

    /**
     * @var JsonSerializer
     */
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * @var JoinProcessorInterface
     */
    private $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Metadata $metadata
     * @param SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory
     * @param CollectionProcessorInterface|null $collectionProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory|null $orderExtensionFactory
     * @param OrderTaxManagementInterface|null $orderTaxManagement
     * @param PaymentAdditionalInfoInterfaceFactory|null $paymentAdditionalInfoFactory
     * @param JsonSerializer|null $serializer
     * @param JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
     */
    public function __construct(
        Metadata $metadata,
        SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory,
        CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor = null,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory = null,
        OrderTaxManagementInterface $orderTaxManagement = null,
        PaymentAdditionalInfoInterfaceFactory $paymentAdditionalInfoFactory = null,
        JsonSerializer $serializer = null,
        JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = null
    ) {
        $this->metadata = $metadata;
        $this->searchResultFactory = $searchResultFactory;
        $this->collectionProcessor = $collectionProcessor ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface::class);
        $this->orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory::class);
        $this->orderTaxManagement = $orderTaxManagement ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(OrderTaxManagementInterface::class);
        $this->paymentAdditionalInfoFactory = $paymentAdditionalInfoFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(PaymentAdditionalInfoInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(JsonSerializer::class);
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(JoinProcessorInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Load entity
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function get($id)
    {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new InputException(__('An ID is needed. Set the ID and try again.'));
        }
        if (!isset($this->registry[$id])) {
            /** @var OrderInterface $entity */
            $entity = $this->metadata->getNewInstance()->load($id);
            if (!$entity->getEntityId()) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                    __("The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again.")
                );
            }
            $this->setOrderTaxDetails($entity);
            $this->setShippingAssignments($entity);
            $this->setPaymentAdditionalInfo($entity);
            $this->registry[$id] = $entity;
        }
        return $this->registry[$id];
    }

    /**
     * Set order tax details to extension attributes.
     *
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @return void
     */
    private function setOrderTaxDetails(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $orderTaxDetails = $this->orderTaxManagement->getOrderTaxDetails($order->getEntityId());
        $appliedTaxes = $orderTaxDetails->getAppliedTaxes();

        $extensionAttributes->setAppliedTaxes($appliedTaxes);
        if (!empty($appliedTaxes)) {
            $extensionAttributes->setConvertingFromQuote(true);
        }

        $items = $orderTaxDetails->getItems();
        $extensionAttributes->setItemAppliedTaxes($items);

        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * Set additional info to the order.
     *
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @return void
     */
    private function setPaymentAdditionalInfo(OrderInterface $order): void
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();

        $objects = [];
        try {
            if (! is_null($order->getPayment()) && ! is_null($order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation())) {
            $paymentAdditionalInformation = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
            foreach ($paymentAdditionalInformation as $key => $value) {
                /** @var PaymentAdditionalInfoInterface $additionalInformationObject */
                $additionalInformationObject = $this->paymentAdditionalInfoFactory->create();
                $additionalInformationObject->setKey($key);

                if (!is_string($value)) {
                    $value = $this->serializer->serialize($value);
                }
                $additionalInformationObject->setValue($value);

                $objects[] = $additionalInformationObject;
            }
            $extensionAttributes->setPaymentAdditionalInfo($objects);
          $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
      }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
        }

    }

    /**
     * Find entities by criteria
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult */
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($searchResult);
        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $searchResult);
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $order) {
            $this->setShippingAssignments($order);
            $this->setOrderTaxDetails($order);
            $this->setPaymentAdditionalInfo($order);
        }
        return $searchResult;
    }

    /**
     * Register entity to delete
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity)
    {
        $this->metadata->getMapper()->delete($entity);
        unset($this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()]);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entity by Id
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function deleteById($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->get($id);
        return $this->delete($entity);
    }

    /**
     * Perform persist operations for one entity
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
        $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($entity->getIsNotVirtual() && $extensionAttributes && $extensionAttributes->getShippingAssignments()) {
            $shippingAssignments = $extensionAttributes->getShippingAssignments();
            if (!empty($shippingAssignments)) {
                $shipping = array_shift($shippingAssignments)->getShipping();
                $entity->setShippingAddress($shipping->getAddress());
                $entity->setShippingMethod($shipping->getMethod());
            }
        }
        $this->metadata->getMapper()->save($entity);
        $this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()] = $entity;
        return $this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()];
    }

    /**
     * Set shipping assignments to extension attributes.
     *
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @return void
     */
    private function setShippingAssignments(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        /** @var OrderExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();

        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
        } elseif ($extensionAttributes->getShippingAssignments() !== null) {
            return;
        }
        /** @var ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment */
        $shippingAssignments = $this->getShippingAssignmentBuilderDependency();
        $shippingAssignments->setOrderId($order->getEntityId());
        $extensionAttributes->setShippingAssignments($shippingAssignments->create());
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * Get the new ShippingAssignmentBuilder dependency for application code
     *
     * @return ShippingAssignmentBuilder
     * @deprecated 100.0.4
     */
    private function getShippingAssignmentBuilderDependency()
    {
        if (!$this->shippingAssignmentBuilder instanceof ShippingAssignmentBuilder) {
            $this->shippingAssignmentBuilder = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder::class
            );
        }
        return $this->shippingAssignmentBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Helper function that adds a FilterGroup to the collection.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     * @return void
     * @deprecated 101.0.0
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     */
    protected function addFilterGroupToCollection(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
    ) {
        $fields = [];
        $conditions = [];
        foreach ($filterGroup->getFilters() as $filter) {
            $condition = $filter->getConditionType() ? $filter->getConditionType() : 'eq';
            $conditions[] = [$condition => $filter->getValue()];
            $fields[] = $filter->getField();
        }
        if ($fields) {
            $searchResult->addFieldToFilter($fields, $conditions);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have tested this orders grid issue in the two ways

```
1. With the replication process
2. Without the replication process
```

1. Using the database replication process, the `sales_order` table records count was not matching with the `sales_order_payment` table records count. So that `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php:172`

(**IMP Note !!!**:   sales_order  count == sales_order_grid count == sales_order_payment count )

**$order->getPayment()** for old orders is returning null, so any function (eg. getAdditionalInformation()) is applying on getPayment() object is giving the error.

The solution is the Need to execute **delta** migration so that whatever the missing records in the `sales_order_payment` table those will create.

1. Without the replication process, we didn't get any issue but after did a full migration we have to verify the sales records whether it is matching or not at the database level in m1 and m2

you can compare the `sales_order` table with the `sales_order_payment` table using this MySQL query::

SELECT * FROM `sales_order` WHERE entity_id NOT IN ( SELECT parent_id from `sales_order_payment`)

after running this query you will get the difference.
It will shows empty if there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

This reason is that the table sales_order_payment is lacking in data. To resolve this error, you must only delete all and re-migrate data again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing payment detail of a specific order, check your source database table sales_order_payment check for the order which show you error and export it and import into your new database it will solve your issue!